# yaml format with question marks and |

Tags: ruby, yaml

i have a strange yaml format with question marks and `"|"`. I converted a tsv file in yml with a ruby code ... What could be wrong in my code so that I have this ?

```
- date: 9/12/2014 20:20:55
  student_id: '1634'
  languages: 'Java, C , HTML , JavaScript , '
  best_language: Java
  app_experience: Native GUI applications, Web Applications, Mobile Applications, Database Driven Applications
  ? |
    tech_experience
  : |
    Unix-based OS, Database, Regular Expressions, Web Design
```

Comment: Show the code that has the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved the problem .... the part where there are "|" and question marks had some line breaks inside (\n) . I used 'require p' to check that .... So I had to chomp the strings and everything went okay.

Answer (score 7):

As specified in [YAML reference](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)

> A question mark and space (“? ”) indicate a complex mapping key.
> Within a block collection, key: value pairs can start immediately
> following the dash, colon, or question mark.
>
> ...
>
> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique. YAML places no further restrictions on the nodes. In particular, keys may be arbitrary nodes, the same node may be used as the value of several key: value pairs, and a mapping could even contain itself as a key or a value (directly or indirectly).